# Why was a question generating a thousand views in seven hours put on hold?

Tags: discussion

> *[Was Nabi Tajima born in the 19th or 20th Century?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443013/was-nabi-tajima-died-this-week-at-117-born-in-the-19th-or-20th-century)*

Within no more than seven hours, over one thousand people (or fewer people many times) thought the question was worth looking at; three people provided answers; twenty up-voted one answer; ten up-voted another; four up-voted the third and comments indicated a lively interest.

What was achieved by putting this question on hold, may I humbly ask ?

Comment: The number of views a question has has exactly 0% relevance to whether that question is on topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be frustrating to have one's question summarily dismissed. Let me try to provide some measure of objectivity from the perspective of a bystander.

1. The question is essentially the same as "[Does the nth century contain the (100n)th year?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/338499/142322)", which deals with the century associated with a year ending in "00".
2. The answer to that question is fairly well-known: centuries start with the x01 year and end with the y00 year, where y=x+1. I didn't participate in the closure of this question, but I gather that this 'common knowledge' was what led to the closure of both questions for lack of research.
3. The numbering of centuries is only tangentially related to the English language. It's arguable that the Romans, [lacking the zero](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/338504/142322), began this numbering scheme, and they didn't use English as their primary language.

Comment: Thank you. Points taken. Appreciated.

Comment: If not closed as off-topic, someone would have closed your main-site question as a duplicate of a [meta-site question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11280/how-does-the-elu-community-define-a-century-when-did-this-century-start-2001-or): first time in history of ELU!

Comment: @EnglishStudent While a neat idea, I don’t think the software would permit that.

Comment: And it may never occur again @Dan Bron.

Comment: @EnglishStudent But it's nice that you gave us the link to that meta. Thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome @NVZ -- I was mainly intrigued that the same Q framed slightly differently could be considered on topic on both ELU and ELU.meta! (That could possibly not happen at IPS.SE)

Comment: Very neat reasoning @JJJ!